# Vuex mapState returns object not array?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to loop over an array of objects using v-for. However my state returns an object containing an array of Objects:

```
{ "todos": [ { "id": "x", "description": "y" }, { "id": "a", "description": "b" } ] }
```

which causes v-for not to work. If I use a getter instead it returns my array of objects like it's supposed to:

```
[ { "id": "x", "description": "y" }, { "id": "a", "description": "b" } ]
```

is this normal behaviour?

using mapState:

```
<template>
    <div class="content-center">
       {{todos}}   
    </div>
</template>
....
import {mapActions, mapGetters, mapState} from 'vuex';

  export default {
        ....
        computed: mapState(['todos'])
    }
```

using getter:

```
<template>
    <div class="content-center">
       {{getTodos}}   
    </div>
</template>
....
import {mapActions, mapGetters, mapState} from 'vuex';

 export default {
        ....
        computed: mapGetters(['getTodos'])
    }
```

I also wanna add that i'm using modules, in case that changes anything about calling the mapState

vuex:

```
const state = {
    todos: []
};

const getters = {

    getTodos: state => state.todos

};

const actions = {
    loadTodos({commit}) {
        axios.get('/api/todos', {
        }).then(response => {
            commit('setTodos', response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setTodos: (state, response) => {
        state.todos = response;
    }
};
```

Comment: show how you use mapState and a getter

Comment: @Anatoly updated my question

Comment: can you share your vuex relevant code as well

Comment: @depperm added :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#object-spread-operator), the `mapState` helper returns an object by default.

The reason why your getter returns an array instead of an object is that a getter must always be a function. In your case, the single line arrow function `state => state.todos` accesses the object and it then implicitly returns the state within the object.

Instead of passing a string array into the helper like `mapState(['todos'])`, you can open it up to perform additional operations (i.e. to access the object) as shown in the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper):

```
computed: mapState({
        todos: state => state.todos
})
```

Notice that you are basically accessing the state the same way the getter was... Only this time you're doing it within the component under the `computed` section.

**Note**: If you have nested modules, you might want to bind your namespaces as shown in the [docs here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace).

Additionally, if you don't need to make use of multiple store state properties or getters, then you could just access that single `todos` property using the `this.$store` shortcut:

```
computed: {
    todos() {
      return this.$store.state.{module_filename}.todos
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Making my modules namespaced fixed the problem, even though I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 1):

> Making my modules namespaced fixed the problem, even though I'm not quite sure why.

Only actions, mutations, and getters get registered in the global namespace, not module state.
[Found here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1592#issuecomment-538759453)
Therefore namespacing solved your issue.

Still you can use mapState without namespacing like this:

```
computed: { 
    ...mapState({
      todos: state => state.FilenameOfYourModule.todos
    })
}
```